# class inheritance with multiple value return typeError

Tags: python, class, inheritance, constructor

```
class Employees:
    def __init__(self, name, dob, contact, email, address):
        self.name = name
        self.dob = dob
        self.contact = contact
        self.email = email
        self.address = address

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Employees class with basic information '

class Clerks(Employees):
    def __init__(self):
        Employees.__init__(self)
        
    def overtime(self):
        pass
        
class Supervisor(Employees):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def get_on_the_piss():
        pass

john = Supervisor('toto','tata', 'titi', 'tete', 'tutu')
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
```

And I done this

```
john = Supervisor()
TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'name', 'dob', 'contact', 'email', and 'address'
```

I tried to shorten the question so I don't post.

```
Clerks class return same result too, 
super(Supervisor, self).__init__() also same result
```

I look onto a lot of solutions but non of them are same and I couldn't find any related documentation  without an keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Employees` takes 5 arguments, so you need to pass them from `Supervisor/Clerks` to its base class.
You can use `*args` and `**kwargs` to shorten your code or `Supervisor/Clerks` need to take at least the same arguments as `Employees`.

```
class Employees:
    def __init__(self, name, dob, contact, email, address):
        self.name = name
        self.dob = dob
        self.contact = contact
        self.email = email
        self.address = address

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Employees class with basic information '

class Clerks(Employees):
    def __init__(self, name, dob, contact, email, address):
        super(Clerks, self).__init__(name, dob, contact, email, address)
        
    def overtime(self):
        pass
        
class Supervisor(Employees):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwarg):
        super(Supervisor, self).__init__(*args, **kwarg)
    
    def get_on_the_piss():
        pass


john = Supervisor('toto','tata', 'titi', 'tete', 'tutu')
print(john.name)

clara = Clerks('clara','tata', 'titi', 'tete', 'tutu')
print(clara.name)
```

Output:

```
toto
clara
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Supervisor class inherits employee class which needs required arguments (that are - name, dob, contact, email, address) to be passed at the time of object declaration.

SO you need to pass these arguments when you are creating john object. just like:

```
john = Supervisor('John', '12/4/2020', '97353', 'emailid@host.com', 'India')
```

Same things with clerk class:

```
clerk1= Supervisor('Rohan', '12/4/2020', '97353', 'emailid@host.com', 'India')
```

Comment: Yes buddy, I did pass correctly at first you can check on the first code last line, but mr.Maurice did point out the problems. cheers